# Progress Bar is incorrect in LongListSelector

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a LongListSelector in my app that contains two TextBlocks and a ProgressBar. The TextBlocks are bound to the same values as the ProgressBars Value and Maximum. This works initially, but when I scroll down the page the progress bar starts to show incorrect values while the TextBlocks remain correct. For example it will display 0 for the value but the progress bar will be completely full.

How can I get around this to get the ProgressBar to show the correct value?

Update: As you can see in this picture.

[image: Notice how the ProgressBar is different from the text on its left/right]

This is the XAML That is causing the issue:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Won}" Grid.Column="0"/>
<ProgressBar Maximum="{Binding Played}" Value="{Binding Won}" Grid.Column="1"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Played}" Grid.Column="2"/>
```

Comment: This looks like a binding issue, can you share the relevant XAML / code behind?

Comment: I've added the XAML to my original post. Do you need the entire ItemTemplate or will that do?

Comment: As Oren suggested, if you look in the Output window while debugging do you see any binding errors ?

Comment: No, I get no errors while running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to be an issue with the control itself which stops updating when it gets into a bad state. In this case (which I can repro easily) the Binding is updating the properties in the wrong order (nothing we can really do about that) and the `ProgressBar` stops updating. I knocked together a quick subclass of ProgressBar that fixes this, cleaning it up is left to you though :)

```
public class RobusterProgressBar : ProgressBar
{

    new public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double), typeof(RobusterProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(ValueChanged));

    new static void ValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (RobusterProgressBar)d;
        control.Value = (double)e.NewValue;
    }

    new public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("Maximum", typeof(double), typeof(RobusterProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(MaximumChanged));

    static void MaximumChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (RobusterProgressBar)d;
        control.Maximum = (double)e.NewValue;
    }

    private double _value;
    new public double Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { 
            _value = value;

            // only update the reflected Value if it is valid
            if (_value <= _maximum)
            {
                Update();
            }
        }
    }

    private double _maximum;
    new public double Maximum
    {
        get { return _maximum; }
        set { 
            _maximum = value;

            // only update the reflected maximum if it is valid
            if (_maximum >= _value)
            {
                Update();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // set all of the ProgressBar values in the correct order so that the ProgressBar 
        // never breaks and stops rendering
        base.Value = 0; // assumes no negatives
        base.Maximum = _maximum;
        base.Value = _value;
    }
}
```

Basically all this does is defer the updates to the real control until all of the numbers are valid (based on the basic `value <= maximum` rule). In my test app the regular `ProgressBar` dies after a while while this version does not.

Incidentally, XAML usage will be the same:

```
<local:RobusterProgressBar Maximum="{Binding Played}" Value="{Binding Won}"/>
```